# 3 server point to point bridge loop

Tags: debian, iptables, bridge

I have a setup with 3 servers (A, B and C) running debian jessie which are all directly connected to the other two servers, so it is a ring-like layout.
I'd like them to only have ohne IP each like if they were connected with a single switch. So I bridged the two interfaces on each server and enabled STP.
It is working fine with one downside: one of the three links between the servers (A to C) is disabled by STP to avoid having a loop. Now A is directly connected with B and B is directly connected with C but traffic from A to C has to go indirectly over B.

What I'd like to have:

- best solution: all connections are enabled at the same time and network packets are just taking the shortest path. And if any link fails the indirect path should be taken. This propably needs some firewall-scripting to be done.
- okay solution: the above with no fallback in case a connection fails. I wanted to achieve this with firewall rules to block forwarding but I wasn't successfull so far. STP still disables one link and ping is possible between all 3 servers. My firewall rules:

  ```
  iptables -t filter -A FORWARD --in-interface tap0 --out-interface tap1 -j DROP
  iptables -t filter -A FORWARD --in-interface tap1 --out-interface tap0 -j DROP
  ```

My next ideas were

- using different parts of the subnet I use on all the Servers so I can filter by IP
- manually managing the MAC addresses for the bridges

But I suspect that that might also fail for some broadcasts.

Maybe there is a better solution. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance